# On Button Press segue not working

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not using the storyboard section to design the UI entirely, but I do have storyboards and segues setup in between VC's. From my splashscreen, I want the viewcontroller to change from one to the next, either through the segue or programatically.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let signupButton = UIButton()
    signupButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(signupButton)
    func pressed (sender:UIButton!){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("RegisterSegue", sender: signupButton)

    }
}
```

This doesn't work (the name of my segue is correct). Can anyone give any insight?

Comment: first, take out the fund pressed(sender:UIButton!) {...} part, that is separate from viewDidLoad().

Comment: try this self.performSegueWithIdentifier("RegisterSegue", sender: self) and func implementation must have outside of viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1):

Your button action method, `pressed:`, must be a top-level function of the view controller, not nested inside viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

How are you performing the segue? If it is a push maybe you need to embed your view controller in a navigation controller. Otherwise use present instead of pushing the view controller.

Answer (score -1):

You need to override the 'Prepare for Segue Method" to replace your current view controller with new one:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
            if (segue.identifier == "RegisterSegue") {

                if let viewController: NewVC = segue.destinationViewController as? NewVC{
                    viewController.passData = "Any data you want to pass"
                }

            }
     }
```

Comment: Not true. You only need a prepareForSegue if you want extra behavior like passing data.

Comment: @DuncanC If you have given manual segue in Storyboard then you need to override "prepareForSegue" method and we don't know that the user has given direct segue or manual segue

Comment: @DuncanC seriously? If it's not true, then it's my bad! Can you put some light on it?